# Is it possible to concreate variable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have some variables and there results which are going into database.

For example

```
        float[] qty1;
        Quote quote = new Quote();
        quote.qty1 = qty1[0];
        quote.qty2 = qty1[1];
        quote.qty3 = qty1[2];
        quote.qty4 = qty1[3];
```

I try to make this process more dynamic

```
           for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
            
            quote.qtyi = qty1[i];
            }
```

please help me how i can use  quote.qtyi and value of i, so it will read quote.qty1, quote.qty2, quote.qty3, quote.qty4

Comment: maybe `Quote.qtyx` should also be an array, as `qtyx` is? That would be the best solutuon

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yup, though I suspect `Quote` may be a DB entity given the first sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Use reflection:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
        
        quote.GetType().GetProperty("qty"+i).SetValue(quote,qt1[i]);

        }
```

quote.getType().getProperty("qty"+i) -> Gets the property called "qty"+i from the object "quote".

.setValue(quote,qt1[i]) -> sets the value "qt1[i]" to the property (if she exists) of the object "quote".

My first answer had TYPOS, now it's compilable

Comment: Code-only answers are particularly unhelpful. Explain what you did and why, also list potential issues (e.g. performance of using reflection)

Comment: in particula when they don't even compile

Comment: Already edited, had some typos now it should work